# What does '&=~' do in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm looking through some c++ code and saw the following and, for my understanding, I want to know what this does. I didn't see anything online other than "The tilde is the destructor"

```
#define i2c_scl_release()                 \
    *_sclDirReg &=~ _sclBitMask
```

I understand the definition, but I'm trying to figure out what `&=~` does.

Ignore any best practices/formatting issues. I found this on github and it's relevant to what I'm looking at so I want to understand it. Both are typed `uint8_t`. Thanks!

Comment: It confuses humans who won't read it correctly as `x &= ~y`.

Answer (score 2):

```
a &=~ b
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = a & (~b)
```

Both `&` and `~` are bitwise operators: `&` is bitwise-and and `~` is bitwise-not.

[See Wikipedia for more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C).

Answer (score 2):

```
*_sclDirReg &=~ _sclBitMask
```

Can be read as:

```
*_sclDirReg =  *_sclDirReg &  (~_sclBitMask)
```

So that line of code:

- Reads the value from `_sclDirReg` (which must be a pointer)
- ANDs it with the bitwise inverse of `_sclBitMask`
- Writes the result back to `_sclBitMask`

Answer (score 0):

It takes the inverse bitmask of `_sclBitMask` and combines it into whatever `_sclDirReg` is pointing at using the bitwise `and` operator.

You could rewrite this as:

```
*_sclDirReg = *_sclDirReg & (~sclBitmask);
```

Answer (score 0):

First the bitmask is inverted `~ _sclBitMask` and then the pointed variable cleared from all bits, which were set in `_sclBitMask` by `*_sclDirReg &=`.

This way you can reset some bit flags, which belong to each other within `_sclDirReg` without touching the rest of the bit flags within it.

Answer (score 0):

It clears (sets to zero) the bits in `*_sclDirReg` that are set (equal to 1) in `_sclBitMask`:

```
 *_sclDirReg =  *_sclDirReg &  (~_sclBitMask)
```

Comment: If type isn't unsigned int, then it's not exactly an equivalent. The assignment family of bitwise operations have curious effect of avoiding promotion (and some undesired effects related to it and presence of sign bit)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie there's *bit mask* in the name, this is a common use case and the question states: "Both are typed uint8_t ".

Comment: Strictly speaking,  result of ~ and & still would be `uint32_t`.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Correct - forgot about all integral types being promoted to the corresponding `signed`/`unsigned` `int` when an operator is applied to them.